# Web Services in C and C++

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to host web services in an existing C/C++ application.  What is the best solution?

I would like a solution similar to what JAX-WS does for Java.  Specifically revolving around SOAP requests.

Any personal experience with available solutions?

Comment: You probably have already, but I think you should consider not using SOAP and consider a RESTful service instead. In my experience, it leads a far cleaner architecture without needing the cruft of XML.

Comment: @dubdubdubdot How have you created C++ web Service. Is it Multi-threaded or parallel execution.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I understand the most popular free solution is gSOAP http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've used gSOAP successfully for a couple of projects.  The APIs it generates can be a little ugly, but it seems stable and it's been able to handle every web service I've thrown at it.

Comment: @MK how did you create a web service in C++. Can you guide or give me some link about it.

Comment: @Mavie Click on the link, it has even a user guide... Please do the effort, it's worth it

Answer (score 8):

You should check out ***[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/)*** from Apache. It has a very nice SOAP implementation & will definitely qualify for one of the best.
It is free and opensource.

Also, have a look at  [***Axis2/C***](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/), it is the C version of the Axis2 architecture, which is way more flexible than Axis1.

Comment: I like how you were able to find kind words for Axis2

Comment: Axis2/C has been failing to provide a new release for 8 years now. Maybe it is not "dead", but at least it is in coma.

Answer (score 5):

I tested Pion at http://www.pion.org/. Deriving from its class `pion::net::WebService` and create HTTP responses is pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best option is to use the [WSO2 Web Services Framework for C++](http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/cpp) because:

1. [It's high-performance](http://wso2.org/library/articles/high-performance-web-services-c)
2. It's easy to integrate
3. [It's easy to use](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/dummys-guide-writing-web-service-clients-wso2-wsf-c) ([Quick start guide](http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/manual_content.html#quick_start))
4. It have a lot of tools around: WSDL2CPP ( Code Generation tool ),
   tcpmon ( SOAP Message viewer ) and WSClient ( command line web
   services client )
5. It have an organic support for WS-Security, WS-Security Policy, WS-Secure Conversation and WS-Reliable Messaging.
6. And my favorite: **Runtime management using WSO2 Carbon based Web Interface**.

See more features [here](http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/index_content.html#wsf_features).

There are [factual comparison results](http://wso2.org/library/articles/high-performance-web-services-c) between [WSO's WSF/C++](http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/cpp) and others Web services implementations with superior results in favor of WSF (*2-3 times better performance*).

WSO2 team and community is very active and the technologies provided by them are highly integrated each other and with 3rds via Open Standards. [Documentation](http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/index.html) and examples are vastly.

Answer (score 2):

1.[XML-RPC](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-xml-rpc/)

2.[WWSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

3.[WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/c/)

The first one looks solid,though I have no hands on Experience.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good alround solution out there for c++ web services as far as I can tell. gSoap works well, but it has been maintained by one person, the original coder for its whole life (high risk). WSO's WSF/C++ Was good but got ditched by WSO onto github with no maintainers! It's had no updates for years, and the current 'build' doesn't!
If anyone can point me at a high performance c++ restful web service kit, with a reasonable prospect of being maintained. I'd appreciate it.