# How to create web service (server & Client) in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: web-services

How to create web service (server & Client) in Visual Studio 2012?
like being done before 2012 as 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I had asked the question when I had recently started my career and was using M.S. Visual Studio 2012; now latest version 2019 is available hence wanted to close this thread.

Comment: I also apologize for delayed reply to accept the answer; actually I had got the solution with my friends at that time but it was my bad that I didn't updated this thread, I was fresher and didn't know how to use these kind of forums. After that I had changed my role in my career and was not using development forums. I publicly apologize here and will take care of it in future.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

When creating a **New Project**, under the language of your choice, select **Web** and then change to **.NET Framework 3.5** and you will get the option of creating an **ASP.NET WEB Service Application**.

[image]

Comment: Why hasn't the guy who asked question accepted this as the right Answer. Anyway thanks

Comment: Right answer! @Sachin Warke?!

Comment: This is technically correct, but NOT a perfect answer. Switching to .Net 3.5 is not the right solution. The answer by Vincenzo Costa better suits the question.

Comment: Can a asp.net web application be created embedding C++ code(using C++ code) in it.

Answer (score 32):

1. Create a new empty Asp.NET Web Application.
2. Solution Explorer right click on the project root.
3. Choose the menu item Add-> Web Service

Comment: This is the current method if not switching back to an older .NET framework. You can add a web service .asmx file to any ASP.NET project as a `New Item`.

Comment: tried, has not worked ( i have no web service in Add - neither in project nor solution)

Comment: Worked for me, by going to Add -> Class... -> Web Service

Comment: Is it possible to create C++ web service in visual studio?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14hykb68(v=vs.80).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542676/web-services-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 12):

WCF is a newer technology that is a viable alternative in many instances.  ASP is great and works well, but I personally prefer WCF.  And you can do it in .Net 4.5.

[image: WCF Project]

[image]

Create a new project.
[image]
Right-Click on the project in solution explorer, select "Add Service Reference"
[image]

Create a textbox and button in the new application.  Below is my click event for the button:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client testClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        //Add error handling, null checks, etc...
        int iValue = int.Parse(txtInput.Text);
        string sResult = testClient.GetData(iValue).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(sResult);
    }
```

And you're done.
[image]

Comment: This was a great example and got me up and running quickly.  Thanks!

Comment: What you write is correct, but is out of the scope of the question. I had the same problem: need to rewrite a Web service that is consumed as an classic Web service, and cannot be updated to WCF as we do not control client side.

Comment: @Robert I don't see "Classic" or "ASP" in the title or question.  I see "How to create web service (server & Client) in Visual Studio 2012?"  I believe I also stated "viable alternative in many cases."  Not *all* cases.  It obviously didn't meet your needs, but you are not on an ASP tagged post.  You are on a web services tagged post.  This is a web service.  Your point is noted, but I must disagree.

Answer (score 2):

--- create a ws server
vs2012 upd 3

1. new project
2. choose .net framework 3.5
3. asp.net web service application
4. right click on the project root
5. choose add service reference
6. choose wsdl

--- how can I create a ws client from a wsdl file?

I´ve a ws server Axis2 under tomcat 7 and I want to test the compatibility

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or a new question? If it's a question you should ask a new question.